# Weka not printing the label for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, bayesian, prediction

I am trying to output the predictions of a test data set after loading a model into weka. The file is in .csv format and the classifier I am using is NaiveBayes. I am setting the supplied test to a test file which has about 110000 instances with label as ?. When I run the model on this test file and output the predictions into a .csv file I get a file like this:

```
inst#  actual  predicted  error  prediction
1        0     0.677      0.677
2        0     0.978      0.978
3        0     1          1
4        0     1          1
5        0     0.991      0.991
6        0     0.996      0.996
7        0     1          1
8        0     0.999      0.999
9        0     0.996      0.996
10       0     0.965      0.965
```

Can anyone tell me why the prediction column is empty? Why isn't the label being printed and how to resolve this.

I am very new to weka and was unable to solve this.

Comment: Isn't the `predicted` column what you need?

Comment: I need the prediction - either s or b(these are the two class values.)

Comment: Can weka do this or not?

Comment: Given that `actual` is reported as `0`, it looks as if you trained on classes `0` and `1`? And `predicted` is the computed value, which for all of these is closer to `1`...

Comment: I had set the label(the value to be predicted) as ? for the test data set. But here, actual is showing 0. The training set had s and b as classes.